# Customize ColorPicker in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I need to make colorPicker functional without having to click a drop down like this:
[image]

It should be always open and other standard controls (like textInput to enter color manually) should not be present.

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement this using the image of color picker and picking up the color where mouse is clicked. Following link will guide you how to do it. This link has demo with source code too for reference.
http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20110414-0347

Answer (score 1):

I'd create custom component based on mx.controls.colorPickerClasses.SwatchPanel, which is class used as a drop down in color picker.

Answer (score 1):

just paste the image of the colorpicker you attached above, add a clicklistener, and based on mouseX, and mouseY of the event, locate the coordinate, and get its color value from the image.